# How to Run Kivy Python programs on PC?

Tags: android, python, kivy

I Need to develop a program which runs on android using python. For this I heard kivy is the best module available. So I tried to install and run kivy on my pc.
Mine is a windows 7 pc.

To achieve this I did the following :

1. I downloaded the package file from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Kivy#downloads
2. Then I opened the package using win rar and pasted the contents to my python27/lib folder

Now when I type the following

```
    import kivy
```

The following message comes :

```
    [INFO              ] [Logger      ] Record log in      
    C:\Users\UserName\.kivy\logs\kivy_16-04-17_4.txt
    [INFO              ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.1
    [INFO              ] [Python      ] v2.7.4 (default, Apr  6 2013, 19:54:46) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]
```

But when I try to run code as simple as this :

```
    import kivy
    from kivy.app import App
    from kivy.uix.label import Label

    class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Label(text='Hello world')


   if __name__ == '__main__':
        MyApp().run()
```

The following error message pops up.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "D:/Python27/unfinished buisness/ufb.py", line 4, in <module>
     from kivy.app import App
    File "D:\Python27\lib\kivy\app.py", line 327, in <module>
     from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
    File "D:\Python27\lib\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 219, in <module>
     from kivy.graphics import (
    File "D:\Python27\lib\kivy\graphics\__init__.py", line 89, in <module>
     from kivy.graphics.instructions import Callback, Canvas, CanvasBase, \
    ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

(But when I run this code on my android phone using Qpython { which comes with kivy already installed } it runs smoothly )

WHere am I going wrong ? Am I installing it wrongly ?

Is it even possible to run Kivy on pc ? or would it only run on android phones ?

Also I would like suggestion for any other modules which we can use to develop android applications using python.

Comment: I've done some work in Kivy about a year ago (on PC, but on Ubuntu). I can't tell you what is wrong, but it ran on my machine without any problems. And as I remember Kivy was, at least at that time developed to be as much cross-platform as it can be. The downside was, that the python code is translated into Java and send via weird mp3 format, causing even very small App (one button to click) to be as ~30MB big, with starting time around 6sec. Anyway, try to contact Kivy devs through their __IRC__ that's the best way imho.

Comment: @quapka mp3 is there only as a "file" containing other files(archive if you wish). Each APK is big, because of python interpreter, but there were suggestions how to make it smaller. APK itself is small(not like pure java though), worse it's with the app _data_, because those are ~30MB. You can use Kivy Launcher(for devs) or hope the situation gets better with devices(there already are models with many times bigger storage than Android 2.3). If you have rooted phone, you can erase unnecessary data. I know it's not desirable, but hey... do you want to code in java?

Comment: Hi @KeyWeeUsr! Please, don't take my previous comment as complains (although I would agree it sounds like it). It's exactly as you said _do you want to code in java?_ I didn't want to, I have nothing against Java, it was just to painful learning Java for some simple App. Therefore I switched immediately to Kivy after I've found it. But it almost made me cry, seeing that it does not give the same possibility. I guess it was too good to be true, at least at that time. I enjoyed using Kivy and had a lot of fun with it (hopefully will). You're one of the Kivy devs, right? Thanks for the good work!

Comment: @quapka Thanks for the compliment, but no.. not from devs, just a common user :D I just wrote it for explaining things as I think the OP is a beginner(at least in kivy), so it could scare him. Actually, you can access java classes and have much more possibilities in way of cross-platform, but yeah, there are limits. As I saw kivy the first time, it was like: "Wow, someone made original java purpose possible? And it is readable?" Try "compile once, run everywhere" lol. Give it a few years and the storage will be much more tolerant for a lot of kivy apps. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have installed kivy, but not properly. As it says, a DLL is missing - an important one and therefore it won't even run. Your code is ok, don't worry about that.

Kivy runs on each platform that Kivy supports, otherwise it'd be kind of... well, you know. Just don't install it with copy&paste and install it the proper way as it's mentioned [here](https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-windows.html) + don't forget to install libraries before you install kivy. For android you'd need to use [`vdi`](https://kivy.org/#download) or it won't be releasable as APK(e.g. for google play).

QPython is a fantastic tool for a beginner, but the cons are that when you have large files, the editor has lags and also they don't use latest kivy afaik.

Also, use `pip` and spare yourself troubles with packages, because sometimes it can be painful. For this purpose I made [KivyInstaller](https://github.com/KeyWeeUsr/KivyInstaller), because beginners sometimes have problems on windows - or mostly people who decide to learn coding with python and kivy first. Not a bad idea though, but they're not reading docs and just skip to word "install" and... here you go.

Recommended packages are basically at [kivy github](https://github.com/kivy) and are very useful if you are going to work on android. There are also [modules](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.modules.html?highlight=modules#module-kivy.modules) especially for kivy that'll help you with developing.

Comment: Thanks for your file @KeyWeeUsr. I deleted my files (which I downloaded manually and copied to Lib) and used your batch file to download kivy again But Again exactly The same warning or error is coming. The message says it coulnt load canvas or canvasbase. (I had all firewalls disabled so there couldnt be any chance of a file not getting installed)

Comment: The error says Dll load failed. Is there any way to find out the name of the dll file it is refering to ?

Comment: @AV198 instrctions.pyd I guess? Or basically anything with `.pyd` and is either missing or compiled wrong. Wheel is already compiled, so... missing only I think. Also I see that you have python 2.7.4, it may be worth to try install python via the KivyInstaller(it'll install 2.7.11, so your 2.7.4 will remain untouched) and try the whole installation from python untill kivy. It's really weird that DLL error even with KivyInstaller O.o

Comment: It didn't help much but thanks anyway. Perhaps its my pc system that's responsible as the installer works fine on my laptop.